# How to select and make blur some parts of image with any HTML5 tech

Tags: javascript, css, html, image, blur

Making it work with latest Chrome browser would be enough for me.

**1-** Selecting image Plugin [Link](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/examples-callback.html#submitting-selection-coordinates-demo)

**2-** Making blur some part of image [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sE4Fv/)

**CSS Codes**

```
.content {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    border:2px solid;
    border-radius:20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 15%;
    left: 15%;
    z-index:10;
    background-color: rgba(168, 235, 255, 0.2);
    /*filter: blur(2px); 
-moz-filter: blur(2px);
-o-filter: blur(2px); 
-ms-filter: blur(2px);*/
}
.background {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url('http://www.travel.com.hk/region/time_95.jpg');
    z-index:2;
    position:fixed;
    /*-webkit-filter: blur(2px);*/
}
.bluredBackground {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    background-image:url('http://www.travel.com.hk/region/time_95.jpg');
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    top:-20%;
    left:-20%;
    padding-left:20%;
    padding-top:20%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
.mask {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    border:2px solid;
    border-radius:20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 15%;
    left: 15%;
    z-index:10;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Img area select gives **x1, y1, x2,** and **y2.**

Tried to place it with map area but impossible give it any css style. How can I merge **1 & 2** examples?